# Linq Sql Query Error for Get value

Tags: linq

Here is my linq query for get Qty and Number from first collection Qty - Second Collection Qty and first collection Number - Second Collection Number, Some times First collection RM not contain second colection

```
var summary = (from r in firstCollection
                       join s in secondCollection
                       on new { r.RM, r.Size } equals new { s.RM, s.Size }
                       group new { r, s } by new { RM = r.RM, Size = s.Size, Qty = (r.Qty - s.Qty), Number = (r.Number - s.Number) }
                           into grp
                           select new
                               {
                                   RM = grp.Key.RM,
                                   RMsize = grp.Key.Size,
                                   Qty = grp.Key.Qty,
                                   Number = grp.Key.Number
                               }).ToList();
```

there is an error like

> Additional information: A group by expression can only contain
>   non-constant scalars that are comparable by the server. The expression
>   with type 'Manufacturing.DataAccess.tbl_RawMaterial' is not
>   comparable.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Your question is unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is `RM` member which I assume is some navigation property of type `Manufacturing.DataAccess.tbl_RawMaterial`. As the exception message states, you can only group by simple properties.

Let say your entity `Manufacturing.DataAccess.tbl_RawMaterial` primary key is called `Id` (you can replace it with the actual name). Then the query could be something like this

```
var summary =
    (from r in firstCollection
     join s in secondCollection
     on new { r.RM.Id, r.Size } equals new { s.RM.Id, s.Size }
     group new { r, s }
     by new { Id = r.RM.Id, Size = s.Size, Qty = (r.Qty - s.Qty), Number = (r.Number - s.Number) }
     into grp
     select new
     {
         RM = grp.FirstOrDefault(e => e.r),
         RMsize = grp.Key.Size,
         Qty = grp.Key.Qty,
         Number = grp.Key.Number
      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can project to anonymous type first and then do a grouping. Try this:

```
var summary = (from r in firstCollection
                join s in secondCollection
                on new { r.RM, r.Size } equals new { s.RM, s.Size }
                select new
                {
                    RM = r.RM,
                    Size = s.Size,
                    Qty = (r.Qty - s.Qty),
                    Number = (r.Number - s.Number)
                } into tmp
                group tmp by new
                {
                    RM,
                    Size,
                    Qty,
                    Number
                } into grp
                select new
                {
                    RM = grp.Key.RM,
                    RMsize = grp.Key.Size,
                    Qty = grp.Key.Qty,
                    Number = grp.Key.Number
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the type of RM and size? I think you should look in Ivan Stoev's answer.